# A realistic example of a one sample mean test for a hypothesized population mean

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, t-test, z-test

One sample mean tests are used to test whether the sample mean is statistically different from a **known** or **hypothesized** population mean. Real life examples given for the latter type (hypothesized population mean) does not seem to be realistic examples. Here is such an example: testing whether the average waiting time in a doctor’s office is greater than one hour. Why does anyone ever want to make such a test? The more reasonable thing to do, in my view, is to try to estimate the average waiting time by giving a confidence interval. But this is something different from trying to reject a hypothesis which claims that the average waiting time is longer than a specific value. My question is, can you give a real life case where we want to do one sample mean test for a **hypothesized** population mean?

Comment: There are myriad examples: consider any kind of situation where a quality target has to be met, for instance, such as a target imposed by government regulations, a customer guarantee, or an engineering constraint. These aren't the only situations.  For instance, sometimes theory (statistical, physical, or something else) stipulates the mean and you wish to test the theory.

Comment: nice examples, thanks.

Comment: one sample mean can't test the hypothesized population mean